# How to plot a function with different conditions (if or which or piecewise)

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, conditional, piecewise

The given function is

[image]

This function is plotted to be

[image]

```
V[x_, r_] := 
 Piecewise[{{-Sqrt[2] r + Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], 
    Abs[x] <= Sqrt[2]/2 r}, {-1 + Sqrt[2] x - Sqrt[
     r^2 - (Abs[x] - 1)^2], Abs[x] >= 1 - Sqrt[2]/2 r}, {-Abs[x],}}]
```

My problem is how to write the **otherwise** condition as given in the paper for the Mathematica and plot the function for different values of r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `-1 + Sqrt[2] x - Sqrt[ r^2 - (Abs[x] - 1)` should be `-1 + Sqrt[2] r -  Sqrt[r^2 - (Abs[x] - 1)^2]`
- The otherwise condition `-Abs[x]` is at the end of all `List`.

```
expr = Piecewise[{{-Sqrt[2] r + Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], 
    Abs[x] <= Sqrt[2]/2 r}, {-1 + Sqrt[2] r - 
     Sqrt[r^2 - (Abs[x] - 1)^2], Abs[x] >= 1 - Sqrt[2]/2 r}}, -Abs[
    x]]
Plot[Table[expr, {r, {.01, .1, .2}}] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Blue}, Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Black, Red, Blue}, {"r=0.2", "r=0.1", "r=0.01"}, 
    LegendMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"], {.2, .8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat the styles in the `PlotLegends`, e.g., `PlotLegends -> Placed[(HoldForm[r = #] & /@ {0.2, 0.1, 0.01}),  {.175, .8}]` I also recommend including `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  Thanks, I also don't know how to add `LegendMarkers`  since I found that `LegendMarkers->Automatic` can not work.